# Getting the values for dependent variable in binary independent variable in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame named orf. I am trying to work out coding on how to calculate the values for dependent variable in binary independent variable e.g Breed. The table gives me the number of breeds in each category. How do I go about coding to calculate for instance the 341 breed type 1 had 500 cases of disease. My y here is Cases

```
table(orf$Breed)
         1   2 
         341 405

    Example: 

Breed   Cases2012
    2   0
    1   0
    2   8
    2   73
    2   0
    2   26
    2   0
    2   45
    1   0
    2   22
    1   0
    1   0
    2   0
    2   6
    1   539
```

Comment: Help us to help you by providing a piece of code you've tried, a piece of your data and (if possible) a desired output. Is very hard try to read your mind.

Comment: tried but get error message: Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: `%>%` is the pipe operator of `magrittr` R package. Try to load `dplyr`.

Comment: Did install dplyr already

Comment: I said load not install. `library(dplyr)` is a very different thing to `install.packages("dplyr")`. Sorry for this very base lesson but if not the case there is a problem with the package.

Comment: Thanks, was me making a mistake in R studio. Worked fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those things there's probably a million ways of doing it in R.

Here's how I'd do it in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Breed) %>%
  summarise(cases = sum(Cases2012))
```

Comment: here is what I tried initially in x tabs: xtabs(~Cases2012 +Breed , data = orf). However it doest give me the number of cases per breed

Comment: Can you tell me more about the breed and the cases variable?

If they factor variables and each observation refers to one case - if so you just need to tabulate them against each other

Comment: Here's some advice about making a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Does table not work?

Comment: Table not work yet. See data sample from the main query post

Comment: Okay, I've seen your data and I've changed my answer - try the new version

Comment: @ Mhairi McNeill rather than doing one variable at a time is there a way I could work out to get the values(cases) for several categorical variables?